# How to find energy function of an audio file?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, librosa, audio-processing

I am loading a wav file using `librosa.load()` or `scipy.io.wavefile.read()`. I need to find the energy function of this signal in terms of magnitude function `s(n)`. If I directly use the values returned by librosa or scipy as `s(n)`, what am I exactly calculating? Can someone please explain in layman terms as I am new to audio processing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you intend to do with the energy function?

Comment: I want to find the rms energy of frames with a 20ms window.

Comment: Why not just use https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.rms.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you hope to get an energy function f(n) from the signal s(n) -- the louder the signal is then the more the energy, then you may take a look at https://musicinformationretrieval.com/energy.html